# UniformGrid with DataTemplate trigger not working as expected, WPF

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, stackpanel, uniformgrid

I host a list of 64 `UserControl` in an `ItemsControl`, the `DataContext` is an array of objects. Then the `DataContext` for the individual instance of the `UserControl` becomes the instance of the object.

The objects have a boolean variable called `Exists`, this is a DataTemplate trigger to determine if the `Usercontrol` will be displayed or not.

I use a `Uniformgrid` to display the list, but I'm experiencing some weird behavior. The `Usercontrol` don't resize. See attached picture. If I use a `StackPanel` instead, it works just fine. But I would like to use the `UnifromGrid` instead.

Here is the code - Only 4 objects have the `Exist` variable set to true.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="gridSome" Background="#FF5AC1F1">
        <Viewbox>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeVM.SomeModel.SomeArray}"  
                          Margin="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <tensioner:UCView  Margin="5"/>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Exists}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <!--<StackPanel IsItemsHost="true"/> This works-->
                        <UniformGrid Columns="1"/> <!-- This does not work-->
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             </ItemsControl>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Uniform Grid]

[image: Stack Panel]

-----Update------

//SSCCE
MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAppItemIssue.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppItemIssue"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <!--<Viewbox>-->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Cars}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="ABC"></TextBox>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding exists}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        <!--</Viewbox>-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfAppItemIssue
{
    class MainViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Model = new MainModel();
        }

        private MainModel model;
        public MainModel Model
        {
            get
            {
                return model;
            }
            set
            {
                model = value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
namespace WpfAppItemIssue
{
    class MainModel
    {
        public Car[] Cars { get; set; }

        public MainModel()
        {
            Cars = new Car[64];
            for (int i = 0; i < Cars.Length; i++)
            {
                Cars[i] = new Car(i);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Car
    {
        public int someVal { get; set; }
        public bool exists { get; set; }

        public Car(int someVal)
        {
            this.someVal = someVal;
            if (someVal < 5)  //Just enable few items for debug
            {
                exists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                exists = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See attached images :

Picture 1 shows Design View. Why are the user controls not being resized?
Picture 2 shows On Execute. Why are the user controls not being resized?
Picture 3 shows On Any resize event. The Controls are being resized correctly.
[image: Design View][image: Execute]
[image: Resize]

Comment: Why do you need a `UniformGrid` if a `StackPanel` works better for you?

Comment: What is the purpose of `Viewbox` in your XAML?

Comment: I want to scale the `ItemsControl` to fit the `Grid`. And, now I want to scale the `UserControls` to fit in the `UniformGrid` in multiple columns.

Comment: I really don't understand why do you need `Viewbox` to fit your `UserControl`'s in cells of `UniformGrid`. All elements placed inside `Grid` or `UniformGrid` have vert/hor alignments set to `Stretch` by default. I even waste some time to write sample app and all my elements in `ItemsControl` succesfully scaled to take all space of a grid's cell. Please show XAML of `UCView`.

Comment: Also you can try to set `Stretch` property of the `Viewbox` to `Uniform` or `Fill`, for example.

Comment: @Maxim - See updated code. I have included `SSCCE`. Here is something interesting - When I compile and execute, the `UserControls` are not resized, they are not resized in the designer view either. But when I maximize the window, the `Usercontrols` are properly resized in the ItemsControl.

Comment: @SanMor See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally got your problem after discussion in comments. It is all about `DataTrigger` in your `ItemTemplate`. Just move it to `ItemContainerStyle` `Triggers` and elements will be resized correctly.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Cars}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding exists}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="ABC"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note that `TextBox`'es will be resized "by border" only (this behavior is shown on your last picture), font size will not be changed. If you want to scale your elements uniformly with their content you really need to wrap `ItemsControl` to `Viewbox`.

Comment: That is it @Maxim ! I have up voted and accepted your answer as the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a weird behavior, but it's the way the `UniformGrid` works.
As an `ItemsPanel` of the `ItemsControl`, the `UniformGrid` uses the `ItemSource` collection to determine the row count and the column count. It doesn't matter whether the items that will be placed in the `UniformGrid` are visible or not - all the grid cells have the same width and height. So your `DataTrigger` has no effect on the layout of the `UniformGrid`, it only affects the visibility of the items.

The `StackPanel` works in a different way. There are no cells, the `StackPanel` arranges all the **visible** items in such a way that they occupy the available space.

Comment: Well, its is weird because at design time - the items take up the available space. When I compile and execute they don't. I cannot use the `StackPanel`, because there are 64 user controls and I would like them to be arranged in multiple rows, which the `UniformGrid` can do.